# How can I type the following in Overleaf?

Tags: amsmath, amssymb

[image]

How can I type the above in overleaf ?

Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass[english,12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathptm}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item  $-2\leqslant x\leqslant 8$.\hfill(2 marks)
    %%%%%%%in \leqslant is < is too wide and = is tilted
%%%%%%% I'm strictly in dire need of the inequalities represented by the screenshot.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What exactly is the issue you’re having? The less than or equal sign? Also, probably not an Overleaf issue.

Comment: the problem is about achieving the type of less symbol shown in the inequality above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-letter-from-a-math-alphabet-or-other-chara)

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is to produce the less-or-equal symbol, I suggest you take a look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21/230692) to the more general question *"How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character?"*

Anyway, `≤` is produced by `\leq`. With the package `amssymb` you also get access to
`⩽`, produced by `\leqslanted`.

Comment: \leq is short compared to the one displayed above